# align inline forms on bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this html code and I'm trying to align some buttons with first input group section.! See atached picture.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <select class="form-control input-xs" name="selectbasic" id="selectbasic1">
                    <option>Option one</option>
                    <option>Option two</option>
                </select>
                <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-plus-sign-alt icon-xs"> </i></a> 
                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-eye-open icon-xs"> </i></a> 
                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-ok-sign icon-xs"> </i></a> 
                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-remove icon-xs"> </i></a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-phone icon-xs"> </i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-phone-sign icon-xs"> </i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="icon-plus-sign-alt"> </i>Alert</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Wrong rendering :[image]

How can I align my buttons from second and third col-md- with first col-md-??? The problem is that the first col-md- section has a select with label ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it. If you want them to be in line with the other buttons, then they should be in the same group col as your other buttons, and then just work some padding magic to make them separate from each other. http://bootply.com/83379 for a working example. Code below:

CSS

```
.input-group-btn:nth-of-type(2) {
  padding:0 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <select class="form-control input-xs" name="selectbasic" id="selectbasic1">
                <option>Option one</option>
                <option>Option two</option>
            </select>
            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-plus-sign-alt icon-xs"> </i></a> 
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-eye-open icon-xs"> </i></a> 
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-ok-sign icon-xs"> </i></a> 
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-remove icon-xs"> </i></a>
          </span>
          <span class="input-group-btn"> 
              <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-phone icon-xs"> </i></a>
              <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> <i class="icon-phone-sign icon-xs"> </i></a>
          </span>
          <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="icon-plus-sign-alt"> </i>Alert</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: IE8 Support

IE8's support for `nth-of-type` is apparently suspect, so if you wanted to ensure support, we can change that CSS rule to be a class, and then add it to the `<span>` with the two buttons in it.

CSS

```
.input-group-btn-padding {
  padding:0 20px;
}
```

See http://bootply.com/83596 for a working example.

Comment: Well, I was trying to avoid adding another class. You could just as easily make that CSS property in to a stand alone class and go from there. I'll update the code in the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use an extra class with margin-top with the form-group?